# Problem with tcblisting: First listed LaTeX command is missing

Tags: listings, tcolorbox

Following code shows the problem. I've declared a `\newtcblisting` with an optional argument.

```
\newtcblisting{codiltxb}[1][]{listing only, #1}
```

When the optional argument is present in further declarations, the listing is correct. (1st and 2nd boxes in figure)

```
\begin{codiltxb}[colback=green!20]
\Some code. Correct if the optional argument is present.
\end{codiltxb}

\begin{codiltxb}[]
\Some code. Correct if the optional argument, although empty, is present.
\end{codiltxb}
```

But if the optional argument is not present and the first word inside listing starts with `\` (like `\LaTeX` commands), this first command disappears from resulting listing. (3rd box)

```
\begin{codiltxb}
\Some code. FAIL! No optional argument. First word (\LaTeX command) missing.
\end{codiltxb}
```

If the optional argument is not present and the first word doesn't start with `\`, the listing is correct again. (4th box)

```
\begin{codiltxb}
Some code. Correct! No optional argument. First word not \LaTeX command.
\end{codiltxb}
```

[image]

What's wrong with my code?

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\newtcblisting{codiltxb}[1][]{listing only, #1}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile]
\frametitle{Listing}

\begin{codiltxb}[colback=green!20]
\Some code. Correct if the optional argument is present.
\end{codiltxb}

\begin{codiltxb}[]
\Some code. Correct if the optional argument, although empty, is present.
\end{codiltxb}

\begin{codiltxb}
\Some code. FAIL! No optional argument. First word (\LaTeX command) missing.
\end{codiltxb}

\begin{codiltxb}
Some code. Correct! No optional argument. First word not \LaTeX command.
\end{codiltxb}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

**Note (2018-06-13)**: Although Thomas F. Sturm answer worked until now, some recent changes (2018-05-12) in `xparse` (see: [xparse gobbles character(s) using an optional argument](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/434928/1952)) make it fail again. A working solution while waiting for a better one is

```
\NewTCBListing{codiltxb}{ !O{} }{listing only, #1}
```

Comment: It seems that the first word is taken as the optional argument

Comment: @MaxNoe. No, in this case fourth example would also fail.

Comment: Definitely a bug. The `\Some` token is not written out in the auxiliary file written by `tcolorbox` (with extension `.listing`). It seems to have to do with the grabbing of the optional argument.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Update: `!O{}` instead of `O{}` inside `\NewTCBListing{codiltxb}{ !O{} }{listing only, #1}` to adapt to `xparse` changes with date of 2018-05-12.

Parsing problems with one optional argument only are known for `\newtcblisting`. The `tcolorbox` manual warns about it on page 245 (v2.60) and recommends to use `\NewTCBListing` instead.

The reason is the grabbing of the optional argument as egreg explained in his answer. It is done by the standard  `\@ifnextchar`, if `\newtcblisting` is used. If `\NewTCBListing` is used, `xparse` code is used which is more suitable for the task.

So, replace

```
\newtcblisting{codiltxb}[1][]{listing only, #1}
```

by

```
\NewTCBListing{codiltxb}{ !O{} }{listing only, #1}
```

and you get the correct result.

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\NewTCBListing{codiltxb}{ !O{} }{listing only, #1}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile]
\frametitle{Listing}

\begin{codiltxb}[colback=green!20]
\Some code. Correct if the optional argument is present.
\end{codiltxb}

\begin{codiltxb}[]
\Some code. Correct if the optional argument, although empty, is present.
\end{codiltxb}

\begin{codiltxb}
\Some code. FAIL! No optional argument. First word (\LaTeX command) missing.
\end{codiltxb}

\begin{codiltxb}
Some code. Correct! No optional argument. First word not \LaTeX command.
\end{codiltxb}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: But the use of the macro `\NewTCBListing` causes error --`Undefined control sequence` in the latest version of `tcolorbox(5.0.2 2022-01-07)`. And its latest manuel still provide this macro on page 324 and 470.

Comment: I mean, besides `\tcbuselibrary{listings}`, what else library needs to be loaded to use the macro `\NewTCBListing`

Comment: @lyl An additional `!` is needed before `O` for `xparse` 2018-05-12 and later. But, I do not get an `Undefined control sequence` error without it.

Answer (score 2):

This has to do with the grabbing of the optional argument; if I use `\new@ifnextchar` of `amsmath` and redefine `\codiltxb` the hard way, I get the expected result; this has the consequence that no space can intervene between the closing brace and the `[`, but should not be a big problem.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newtcblisting{codiltxb}[1][]{listing only, #1}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\codiltxb}{%
  \new@ifnextchar[\@codiltxb{\tcblisting {listing only,options@for=codiltxb}}%
}
\def\@codiltxb[#1]{\tcblisting {listing only,#1,options@for=codiltxb}}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\begin{codiltxb}[colback=green!20]
\Some code. Correct if the optional argument is present.
\end{codiltxb}

\begin{codiltxb}[]
\Some code. Correct if the optional argument, although empty, is present.
\end{codiltxb}

\begin{codiltxb}
\Some code. FAIL! No optional argument. First word (\LaTeX command) missing.
\end{codiltxb}

\begin{codiltxb}
Some code. Correct! No optional argument. First word not \LaTeX command.
\end{codiltxb}

\end{document}
```

[image]