# xparse gobbles character(s) using an optional argument

Tags: xparse

Some recent change of the `xparse` package or of the LaTeX3 fundament seems to yield some changed behaviour regarding parameter processing. In some situations, at least one character is gobbled where it should not.

The following MWE shows a rather harmless situation, but my real problem is that an enironment based on `xparse` with verbatim text removes the first character of this text, see https://github.com/T-F-S/tcolorbox/issues/43

The MWE constructs an environment `myenv` with one optional argument. If this argument is not used, the whitespace is gobbled. Used in a more complicated scenario, as mentioned above, crucial stuff can be gobbled.

There is a second environment `myENV` without arguments to show the expected behaviour.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\NewDocumentEnvironment{myenv}{ O{} }{Alpha}{Omega}

\NewDocumentEnvironment{myENV}{}{Alpha}{Omega}

\begin{document}

\begin{myenv}[parameter]
Test
\end{myenv}

\begin{myenv}[]
Test
\end{myenv}

\begin{myenv}
Test
\end{myenv}

\begin{myENV}
Test
\end{myENV}

\end{document}
```

If this code is compiled against an installation of `xparse (2018/02/21)`, the output is as expected:

[image]

But, if this code is compiled against an installation of `xparse (2018/04/30)` or `xparse (2018/05/12)`, the output is:

[image]

I consider this to be a bug. But, if this is a feature, how can I get rid of it? Is there a way to have the old behaviour back with clean or dirty tricks which could help to solve my real problem (see above)?

Comment: Maybe https://www.texdev.net/2018/04/21/xparse-optional-arguments-at-the-end/ explains the change you are seeing

Comment: `!O{}` as optional argument works.

Comment: @moewe Yes, that's it! Would you like to add an answer which I could accept?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I feared that it is a feature... At least `!` gives back the old behaviour. Unfortunately, a *lot of* documents have to be changed now...

Comment: Yes, but I'm not completly sure that it is a feature, the blog describes spaces *before* the argument. @JosephWright is needed.

Comment: Indeed, seeing that the blogpost is (as I read it exclusively) about spaces and in your real-world bug report more than that goes missing, I'd rather not answer and leave the field for an expert instead.

Comment: Yes, I also think it is wise to wait, whether the implementation is really as intended before changing many documents...

Comment: I've got to adjust few things here ...

Comment: @UlrikeFischer The former behaviour meant that [..] had to follow immediately `\begin{}` else it would not be recognized as optional argument. The new behaviour by default relaxes this. But from far away it looks strange to make default the behaviour which will cause `[]` with a space before, which was not recognized as optional argument so far, be now recognized as optional argument.

Comment: One would normally expect environments such as the ones given to be `\ignorespaces` at the start ... in any case, we know we need to adjust a few things here

Comment: @JosephWright Yes, but the MWE is just to show the effect.

Comment: We may need to think about environments as needing separate treatment from commands ...

Comment: I cannot reproduce the error with `xparse (2019-05-28)`, so I assume the bug is fixed and will vote to close this question.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was based on a bug that has been fixed.