# Tcblisting with one optional argument, which has a default value not working (even with xparse and \NewTCBListing)

Tags: tcolorbox, xparse

I would like to use `tcolorbox listing` environments to format listings in an interesting way. For each listing, I would like to have an title in a way, that in default it would be like `Listing (number)`, but if specified (as optional argument) it would be the specified text. This text should be also used in underlay as a decoration.

In next MWE, **first** environment `clisting` works, but has no parametrization and mainly shows, what I am trying to achieve.

**Second** environment `cxparselisting` shows how I thought it should be achieved. `/tcb/xparse` library command `\NewTCBListing` is used and `O{text}` is used for `text` to be used for `#1`, but it doesnt work and in stated `cxparselisting` content first letter `#` is interpreted as optional argument (as described here: [Problem with tcblisting: First listed LaTeX command is missing](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/247643/problem-with-tcblisting-first-listed-latex-command-is-missing) ).

I must have misunderstood, how to create optiOnal arguments in `xparse`.

**Third** environment, `xmllisting` shows also what I want to achieve, and surprisingly works with non-`xparse` syntax (eventhough first *?token* *tab* is absorbed).

How can I construct (preferably) `\NewTCBListing` to have one optional argument with default value (that is parametrized, so can be used in multiple tcbox options)?

MWE: (delete % near comment environments to disable not-working `cxparselisting` and be able to compile MWE)

```
\documentclass [a4paper, 11pt, twoside, openright] {scrbook}

\usepackage{comment}

\usepackage[dvipsnames,x11names,svgnames,table]{xcolor}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\usepackage[skins, vignette, breakable, hooks, xparse, minted, raster]{tcolorbox}
\tcbset{listing engine=minted}

\newcounter{ccounter}

\newtcblisting[use counter=ccounter]{clisting}{% Works, but without parametrization
    colframe=green!75!black,%
    listing only,%
%   title=#1,
    title=C listing \theccounter,
    minted language=C,
    underlay middle and last={%
    \ifnumequal{\numexpr\tcbsegmentstate}{2}{\begin{tcbclipinterior}\fill[red!10!blue!10!white] ([xshift=-7mm]frame.south east)
      rectangle (frame.north east) node [anchor=south east,rotate=90] {\bfseries \textcolor{black}{C listing \theccounter -- Output}};\end{tcbclipinterior}%
    }
    {\begin{tcbclipinterior}\fill[red!10!blue!10!white] ([xshift=-7mm]frame.south east)
      rectangle (frame.north east) node [anchor=south east,rotate=90] {\bfseries \textcolor{black}{C listing \theccounter}};\end{tcbclipinterior}%
    }
    },% 
}

%\begin{comment}
\NewTCBListing[use counter=ccounter]{cxparselisting}{ O{C~listing~\theccounter} }{% Doesnt work, probably still grabs first letter in optional argument scan
    colframe=green!75!black,%
    listing only,%
    title=#1,
    minted language=C,
    underlay middle and last={%
    \ifnumequal{\numexpr\tcbsegmentstate}{2}{\begin{tcbclipinterior}\fill[red!10!blue!10!white] ([xshift=-7mm]frame.south east)
      rectangle (frame.north east) node [anchor=south east,rotate=90] {\bfseries \textcolor{black}{#1 -- Output}};\end{tcbclipinterior}%
    }
    {\begin{tcbclipinterior}\fill[red!10!blue!10!white] ([xshift=-7mm]frame.south east)
      rectangle (frame.north east) node [anchor=south east,rotate=90] {\bfseries \textcolor{black}{#1}};\end{tcbclipinterior}%
    }
    },% 
}
%\end{comment}

\newcounter{xmlcounter}

\newtcblisting[use counter=xmlcounter]{xmllisting}[1][XML listing \thexmlcounter]{% Surprisingly, works ...
    colframe=blue!75!black,%
    listing only,%
    title=#1,
    minted language=XML,
    underlay middle and last={%
    \ifnumequal{\numexpr\tcbsegmentstate}{2}{\begin{tcbclipinterior}\fill[red!10!blue!10!white] ([xshift=-7mm]frame.south east)
      rectangle (frame.north east) node [anchor=south east,rotate=90] {\bfseries \textcolor{black}{#1 -- Output}};\end{tcbclipinterior}%
    }
    {\begin{tcbclipinterior}\fill[red!10!blue!10!white] ([xshift=-7mm]frame.south east)
      rectangle (frame.north east) node [anchor=south east,rotate=90] {\bfseries \textcolor{black}{#1}};\end{tcbclipinterior}%
    }
    },% 
}

\begin{document}
\begin{clisting}
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  printf(''Hello World!\n'');
  return 0;
}
\end{clisting}

\bigskip

%\begin{comment}
\begin{cxparselisting}
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  printf(''Hello World!\n'');
  return 0;
}
\end{cxparselisting}
%\end{comment}

\bigskip

\begin{xmllisting}
    <message>
    <text>Hello, world!</text>
    </message>
\end{xmllisting}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On page 453 of the `tcolorbox` documentation the problem is explained:

> With date of 2018-05-12, the xparse [13] package changed the argument
>   collection process. Now, spaces are ignored which leads to a serious
>   change for listing environments ending with an optional argument like
>   O{}. The former behaviour of respecting spaces can be preserved by
>   adding a «!».

`xparse` was adapted later to reduce the occurrences of that problem,
but for `tcblisting` the statement of the documentation is still true 
(unfortunately).

So, you have to replace

```
\NewTCBListing[use counter=ccounter]{cxparselisting}{ O{C~listing~\theccounter} }{%
```

by

```
\NewTCBListing[use counter=ccounter]{cxparselisting}{ !O{C~listing~\theccounter} }{%
```

to solve (circumvent) the problem.